# Amazon Alexa Skill S3 Restrictions

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I'm using Lambda and S3 in conjunction with Amazon's Skills Kit. The Lambda is running Node.js and referencing audio files which I use SSML for playback on Alexa commands. However, since I get charged for GET requests, I'd like to limit the requests to just the servers requesting specifically from Alexa. Although I can set an IAM user to restrict access, I think I'll get an access denied response when trying to play back from Alexa. Can I restrict playback based on a known Alexa IP? It appears that the IAM information isn't passed through regular HTTP requests to S3 GETs.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could daisy-chain lambda requests. Have one lambda function to handle the Alexa app, and if an intent involves an audio file, call another lambda function.